# Spicetify extension to generate a playlist of songs with similar audio features

Tags: javascript

I decided to make an extension for Spicetify (modified Spotify client). It generates a playlist of similar songs based on their average audio features.

```
//@ts-check

// NAME: Feature Shuffle
// AUTHOR: CharlieS1103
// DESCRIPTION: Create a playlist based on the average features of a playlist

/// <reference path="../globals.d.ts" />

(function songstats() {

    const {
        CosmosAsync,
        Player,
        LocalStorage,
        PlaybackControl,
        ContextMenu,
        URI
    } = Spicetify;
    if (!(CosmosAsync && URI)) {
        setTimeout(songstats, 300)
        return
    }


    const buttontxt = "Create Feature Based Playlist"

    const average = (array) => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b) / array.length;

    async function makePlaylist(uris) {
        const uri = uris[0];
        const uriObj = Spicetify.URI.fromString(uri);
        const uriFinal = uri.split(":")[2]

        const user = await CosmosAsync.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me')

        const playlistitems = (await CosmosAsync.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/' + uriFinal + '/tracks')).items.map(i => i.track.href);






        const avrDanceability = [];

        const avrTempo = [];

        const avrEnergy = [];

        const avrAcousticness = [];

        const avrInstrumentalness = [];

        const avrSpeechiness = [];

        const avrLiveness = [];

        var avr2Dance

        var avr2Tempo

        var avr2Energy

        var avr2Acoustic

        var avr2Intrumentalness

        var avr2Speechiness

        var avr2Liveness
        for (i = 0; i < playlistitems.length; i++) {
            var songuri = playlistitems[i].split("/")[5]
            var res;
            try {
                res = await CosmosAsync.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/' + songuri);
            } catch (error) {
                //e
            }

            avrDanceability.push(Math.round(100 * res.danceability) / 100);

            avrEnergy.push(Math.round(100 * res.energy) / 100);

            avrAcousticness.push(Math.round(100 * res.acousticness) / 100);

            avrInstrumentalness.push(Math.round(100 * res.instrumentalness) / 100);

            avrSpeechiness.push(Math.round(100 * res.speechiness) / 100);

            avrTempo.push(Math.round(100 * res.tempo) / 100);

            avrLiveness.push(Math.round(100 * res.liveness) / 100);
        }


        avr2Dance = average(avrDanceability);

        avr2Acoustic = average(avrAcousticness);

        avr2Tempo = average(avrTempo)

        avr2Energy = average(avrEnergy)

        avr2Intrumentalness = average(avrInstrumentalness)

        avr2Liveness = average(avrLiveness)

        avr2Speechiness = average(avrSpeechiness)



        const randomSongrequest = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 21; i++) {

            const getRandomSongsArray = ['%25-%25', '-%25', '%25-%25', '-%25', '%25-%25', '-%25', '%25-%25', '-%25'];
            const rndInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1

            var ranSong = getRandomSongsArray[Math.floor(Math.random() * getRandomSongsArray.length)];


            function randAlph(rndInt, ) {

                const alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
                const letters = []

                for (var i = 0; i < rndInt; i++) {
                    const randomletter = alphabet[Math.floor(Math.random() * alphabet.length)]
                    letters.push(randomletter)
                }
                const string = letters.join("")
                return (string)
            }

            const ranString = randAlph(rndInt)

            const getRandomSongs = ranSong.replace("-", ranString)

            const getRandomOffset = Math.floor(Math.random() * (600 - 1 + 1) + 1)

            const url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=" + getRandomSongs + '&offset=' + getRandomOffset + "&type=track&limit=1&market=US";

            const randomSongrequestToAppend = (await CosmosAsync.get(url)).tracks.items.map(track => track.uri);






            if (randomSongrequestToAppend[0] != undefined) {

                let res2 = await CosmosAsync.get('https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/' + randomSongrequestToAppend[0].split(":")[2]);

                if (Math.round(100 * res2.liveness) / 100 >= avr2Liveness - 20 && Math.round(100 * res2.liveness) / 100 <= avr2Liveness + 20) {

                    if (res2.tempo >= avr2Tempo - 5 && res2.tempo <= avr2Tempo + 5) {

                        if (Math.round(100 * res2.instrumentalness) / 100 >= avr2Intrumentalness - 20 && Math.round(100 * res2.instrumentalness) / 100 <= avr2Intrumentalness + 20) {

                            if (Math.round(100 * res2.energy) / 100 >= avr2Energy - 20 && Math.round(100 * res2.energy) / 100 <= avr2Energy + 20) {

                                if (Math.round(100 * res2.danceability) / 100 >= avr2Dance - 20 && Math.round(100 * res2.danceability) / 100 <= avr2Dance + 20) {

                                    randomSongrequest.push(randomSongrequestToAppend[0])
                                    console.log("Song passed")
                                } else {

                                    i--
                                }
                            } else {
                                i--

                            }
                        } else {
                            i--

                        }
                    } else {
                        i--

                    }
                } else {
                    i--

                }

            } else {
                i--

            }

        }




        const newplaylist = await CosmosAsync.post('https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/' + user.id + '/playlists', {
            name: 'New Playlist'
        });

        const playlisturi = newplaylist.uri.split(":")[2]

        const addToPlaylist = CosmosAsync.post('https://api.spotify.com/v1/playlists/' + playlisturi + '/tracks', {
            uris: randomSongrequest
        });


    }

    function shouldDisplayContextMenu(uris) {

        if (uris.length > 1) {
            return false;
        }

        const uri = uris[0];
        const uriObj = Spicetify.URI.fromString(uri);


        if (uriObj.type === Spicetify.URI.Type.PLAYLIST_V2) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    const cntxMenu = new Spicetify.ContextMenu.Item(

        buttontxt,
        makePlaylist,
        shouldDisplayContextMenu,

    );

    cntxMenu.register();
})();
```

The actual logistics of how it works doesn't matter that much as the main issue is it looking godawful; if you're interested in seeing how to make Spicetify extensions the only way to learn is to look at the spicetify-cli source code, and utilize already existing extensions' source code as reference.

The fact that there are no tutorials on Spicetify development, and the fact that I neglected to actually learn JavaScript combined to make this a hellish code.

Answer (score 1):

- Repeated code: `Math.round(num * 100) / 100` is constantly repeated. Extract it to a function
- Nested `if` statements: You have an awful lot of nested `if` statements that could be one simple `if`:

  ```js
  if (something) {
    if (somethingElse) {
      doStuff();
    } else {
      i--;
    }
  } else {
    i--;
  }
  ```

  Can be rewritten as (in a much more readable way):

  ```js
  if (something
      && somethingElse) {
    doStuff();
  } else {
    i--;
  }
  ```
- Unnecessary empty lines: Empty lines are useful if you wish the separate certain parts of the code. But if you add them to every single line, it just makes code harder to read. E.g.

  ```js
  avr2Dance = average(avrDanceability);

  avr2Acoustic = average(avrAcousticness);

  avr2Tempo = average(avrTempo)

  avr2Energy = average(avrEnergy)

  avr2Intrumentalness = average(avrInstrumentalness)

  avr2Liveness = average(avrLiveness)

  avr2Speechiness = average(avrSpeechiness)
  ```

  Is less readable than:

  ```js
  avr2Dance = average(avrDanceability);
  avr2Acoustic = average(avrAcousticness);
  avr2Tempo = average(avrTempo)
  avr2Energy = average(avrEnergy)
  avr2Intrumentalness = average(avrInstrumentalness)
  avr2Liveness = average(avrLiveness)
  avr2Speechiness = average(avrSpeechiness)
  ```